# Proper Way To Compare Short Dates (SQL Server 2005)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, datetime

Currently I'm comparing short dates this way:

```
CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), return_date,101)) = '{0}'
```

My supervisor says that I should do it this way:

```
datepart(month,return_date)= 5   
and  datepart(day,return_date)=24   
and  datepart(year,return_date)=2011
```

because the defined value 101 recognized by the function CONVERT might change in the future. Is that true? How often do these parameter values change? Have the changed in the past? Is there an even better way to compare the short form of dates?

Comment: if your two dates are in short date data type you don't need convert or datepart. you can compare as simple as: where dt1 = dt2

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that we are comparing dates that DO have time components, hence the need for comparing only the date components and not time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "short dates" you mean "just the date without the time"

```
Select ...
From MyTable
Where return_date >= '20110524'
    And return_date < DateAdd(d, 1, '20110524')
```

First, note the `<` in the second part of the Where clause. Second, if there is an index on `return_date`, this approach will use it. Another solution which would not utilize an index (and thus result in a table scan) would be:

```
Select ...
From MyTable
Where DateAdd(d, DateDiff(d, 0, return_date), 0) = '20110524'
```

If `return_date` is always stored without its time component (i.e., its time component is always midnight) then you can do a simple comparison:

```
Select ...
From MyTable
Where return_date = '20110524'
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Could you also share your opinion on whether or not there is a possibility that the CONVERT function's paramater for date format might change?

Comment: @enamrik - It probably will not change but that is also not the best way to compare dates. By executing a function on the column, you will force a table scan regardless of whether you have an index on return_date or not. If the values in return_date can have a time component, then my first solution is the best. If the values in return_date will never have a time component, then my last solution is the best. You shouldn't need to use Convert.

Comment: @enamrik - Btw, let me also add that in SQL Server 2008, there is a `Date` data type which only stores the date portion and should eliminate this problem of stripping the time component.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. We actual need the time component but your insight into indexing gave me the answer I didn't know I was looking for, THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Outside of adding conversion styles, `convert()` and its conversion styles haven't changed since SQL Server 4.2, c. 1992, when it was bundled with OS/2.

Comment: +1 Agreed. That would be a major breaking change. Chances are slim-none.

Comment: Thanks, I'm searching for documentation to prove this right now. I can't wait to tell my supervisor, I can already taste it!

Answer (score 0):

This is my preference:

```
SELECT foo
FROM bar
WHERE return_date = CONVERT(datetime, FLOOR(CONVERT(float, Getdate())))
```

or, if return_date has a time stamp

```
SELECT foo
FROM bar
WHERE CONVERT(datetime, FLOOR(CONVERT(float, return_date))) = CONVERT(datetime, FLOOR(CONVERT(float, Getdate())))
```